# Parsing\iterating thru JSON `bad` arrays in javascript with jquery. Ho to parse such thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have JSON returned from my server like:

```
 {
    "user": {
        "nickname": "Ann",
        "width": 90,
        "height": 60
    },
    "user": {
        "nickname": "Dan",
        "width": 60,
        "height": 90
    }
}
```

I need to iterate thru all users and for example alert thare nicknames so I try next code:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{    "user": {        "nickname": "ole",        "width": 333,        "height": 222    },    "user": {        "nickname": "jak",        "width": 333,   "height": 222 }}');
for (user in obj ) {
   alert( obj[user][nickname]);
}
```

Which fails. What shall I do to alert all user names (I cant change how server returns json=( so I hope to find solution on JS side.)

Code is [dying alive here.](http://jsfiddle.net/uDdbq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, if you want to do this reliably, you can modify an existing pure JS JSON parser. For instance, take a look at Douglas Crockford's simple recursive descent parser "parse_json": https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js

At **line 272** (in the object function) we have:

```
if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
    error('Duplicate key "' + key + '"');
}
object[key] = value();
```

We could replace this with:

```
if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
     if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(dupKeys, key) && dupKeys[key]) {
         object[key].push(value());
     } else {
         object[key] = [ object[key], value() ];
         dupKeys[key] = true;
     }
} else {
     object[key] = value();
}
```

Of course, around **line 259** we'd have to add the variable dupKeys,

```
var key,
    object = {},
    dupKeys = {};
```

And then json_parse would parse your JS.

```
var obj = json_parse("... your bad JSON here ...");
obj.user.forEach(function(user) {
    alert(user["nickname"]);
});
```

Comment: BTW: are Duplicated keys illegal in official JSON specification?

Comment: Yes. Although the grammar doesn't explicitly forbid it, I don't think you'd find a valid parser that would parse it the way you want. To me, the correct behaviour would be to overwrite the previous entry at the key with the new value. However, Douglas Crockford is The Man, so hard to say.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is you have an array inside and array.   You need to use something like

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('[ {"user": {        "nickname": "ole",        "width": 333,        "height": 222    }},    {"user": {        "nickname": "jak",        "width": 333,   "height": 222 }}]');
for (i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
     alert(obj[i].user.nickname);
}
```

Each "user" is part of the array i.e. 0,1...

Also, as others have pointed out.  You need to put the names in quotes.

Lastly, the JSON was wrong.  As you can see it should have contained the array brackets.  This code works.  You can reference well formed JSON at [www.json.org](http://www.json.org).  Ultimately the server is going to have to give you valid JSON if you want to iterate users.

Comment: Give the code above a try.  The JSON was "wrong" while it parsed you only could view the first USER.  Chrome debugger pointed this out if you do a console.log(obj) of your original object, only one "user" showed up because the JSON was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Change nickname to "nickname" since you don't have a variable defined for it:

```
alert( obj[user]["nickname"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues.

First, keys must be unique. You're using the key `user` twice in the same object notation. You'd be better to use array notation.

Second, `[nickname]` should be `.nickname` or `["nickname"]`.

```
var json = '{    "user": {        "nickname": "ole",        "width": 333,        "height": 222    },    "user": {        "nickname": "jak",        "width": 333,   "height": 222 }}';

   // make it an Array
json = '[' + json.slice(1,-1).replace(/"user":/g,'') + ']';

var obj = $.parseJSON( json );

for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++ ) {
   alert( obj[i].nickname);
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/z7YxR/

Comment: Is it possible to go around that issue with unique `user` key?

Comment: @Kabumbus: I updated my answer. Yes, since they're all users, you don't need to label each one as "user". Just use array notation, which will be parsed into a JavaScript Array with numeric indices.

Comment: @Kabumbus: Just noticed that you can't fix the markup server-side. I've updated to show how to fix it on the client.

Comment: @patrick dw while fixing the server side data may be what he ultimately needs to do it's really BAD that the server side code remains invalid JSON data. Someone on the other end needs to fix that.  Enough bad code in the world already, compensating for it is silly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't change your JSON server-side you need to change it client-side before you parse it.

Given the JSON mentioned you could use this function:

```
function fixData( d ) {
    d = d.replace(/,\s*\"user\"\:/, ",");
    d = d.replace(/\"user\"\:/, "\"users\":[");
    d = d.replace(/}\s*$/, "]}");
    return d;
}
```

And simply "fix" the JSON before running `parseJSON` via:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(fixData(/* JSON string */));
```

[Fiddle with my solve](http://jsfiddle.net/jswartwood/uDdbq/4/)

If you would like to then loop through each user and output "nickname":

```
jQuery.each(obj.users, function(){ alert(this.nickname); });
```

**Please note:** Obviously the regex in the the `fixData` function is fragile and shouldn't be used as a general solve for any other data sources; you would need to rewrite it to your specific use case if it doesn't match exactly.

Comment: Also, I highly recommend that you look to modify the server-side JSON response (similar to @patrick_dw's suggestion) as it is invalid.  This should only be used as a shim until that day.